# How to create an AWS EC2 instance with 12GB RAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How to create an AWS EC2 instance with 12GB RAM. I see t2.large, t2.xlarge which is 8GB and 16GB memory, but I need the flexibility to use 12GB instead

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/high-memory/

Comment: @YeshwinVermaTheProgrammer I think the ones available on that page are 12TB, not 12GB machines :)

Comment: Sorry I will check by the way why dont you use 16 gb ram?

Comment: I'd be happy to be proven wrong, but I think your only option is to allocate a 16GB machine and limit the RAM used in other ways (ie OS boot options). Which OS are you running?

Comment: Also i dont think high ram will affect application performance but it will improve it.

Comment: It affects my budget, I just need a 12 GB machine right now I use a 8 GB machine

Comment: Nope, there is a specific list of instances and that you can choose from. If it is only due to budget reasons, then there is a number of other, more flexible VPS providers (though without security and robusness of AWS)

Answer (score 0):

If you want exactly 12GB of Ram, you can use 3 t4g.xlarge instance and connect them with a Application Load Balancer.

you can find all about load balancer here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html

Comment: From what I see ` t4g.xlarge` has 16 GB of RAM, not 12?

Comment: need it on a single machine not multiple machines

Comment: 12GB option is not availble for now as far as i know.